# Trying to flatten JSON file but getting error using PySpark

Tags: python, json, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a JSON file and I need to convert it into tabular form by using only Pyspark.
My JSON file :-

```
{
    "records": [
        {
            "name": "Priya",
            "last_name": "Munjal",
            "special_values": [
                {
                    "name": "adress",
                    "value": "some adress"
                },
                {
                    "name": "city",
                    "value": "Chd"
                },
                {
                    "name": "zip_code",
                    "value": "134112"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Neha",
            "last_name": "Miglani",
            "special_values": [
                {
                    "name": "adress",
                    "value": "some adress"
                },
                {
                    "name": "city",
                    "value": "kkr"
                },
                {
                    "name": "zip_code",
                    "value": "02221"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Result that I want :-

```
name|last_name|address|city|zip_code

priya|munjal|some adress|Chd|02193

neha|miglani|some adress|kkr|02221
```

I have tried this code :-

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, explode

# Initialize SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("JSONTransformation").getOrCreate()

# Read the input JSON file
input_path = "path_to_your_spark_ex.json"
df = spark.read.json(input_path)

# Explode the 'records' array and select required columns
flattened_df = df.select(
    explode(col('records')).alias('record')
).select(
    col('record.name').alias('name'),
    col('record.last_name').alias('last_name'),
    col('record.special_values').alias('special_values')
)

# Create a DataFrame from the 'special_values' array
values_df = flattened_df.select(
    col('name'),
    col('last_name'),
    col('special_values')[0]['value'].alias('address'),
    col('special_values')[1]['value'].alias('city'),
    col('special_values')[2]['value'].alias('zip_code')
)

# Show the result
values_df.show()

# Stop SparkSession
spark.stop()
```

but not getting the result. I have done using Pandas but need to be done only in Pyspark now

Answer (score 0):

1. Extract value from array using `special_values.value`
2. Use `concat_ws` function to concat array of string as comma separated values.
3. Use `from_csv` function to apply schema to the comma separated values
4. Use `*` to extract attributes from `struct` data type.

```
from_csv( 
     concat_ws( 
        ',',
        special_values.value
     ), 
     'address string, city string, zip_code string'
)
```

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
```

```
>>> df.show(10, False)
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|records                                                                                                                                              |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|[{Munjal, Priya, [{adress, some adress}, {city, Chd}, {zip_code, 134112}]}, {Miglani, Neha, [{adress, some adress}, {city, kkr}, {zip_code, 02221}]}]|
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

```
df\
.select(explode(col('records')).alias('records'))\
.select(col('records.*'))\
.withColumn('special_values', expr('''from_csv(concat_ws(',',special_values.value), 'address string, city string, zip_code string')'''))\
.select('name','last_name','special_values.*')\
.show(10, False)
```

```
+-----+---------+-----------+----+--------+
|name |last_name|address    |city|zip_code|
+-----+---------+-----------+----+--------+
|Priya|Munjal   |some adress|Chd |134112  |
|Neha |Miglani  |some adress|kkr |02221   |
+-----+---------+-----------+----+--------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works for me after I add `.option('multiLine', True)` to the read method.

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, explode

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("JSONTransformation").getOrCreate()

df = (
    spark.read
    .option('multiLine', True)
    .json('data.json')
)

# Explode the 'records' array and select required columns
flattened_df = df.select(
    explode(col('records')).alias('record')
).select(
    col('record.name').alias('name'),
    col('record.last_name').alias('last_name'),
    col('record.special_values').alias('special_values')
)

# Create a DataFrame from the 'special_values' array
values_df = flattened_df.select(
    col('name'),
    col('last_name'),
    col('special_values')[0]['value'].alias('address'),
    col('special_values')[1]['value'].alias('city'),
    col('special_values')[2]['value'].alias('zip_code')
)

# Show the result
values_df.show()
```

Result:

```
+-----+---------+-----------+----+--------+
| name|last_name|    address|city|zip_code|
+-----+---------+-----------+----+--------+
|Priya|   Munjal|some adress| Chd|  134112|
| Neha|  Miglani|some adress| kkr|   02221|
+-----+---------+-----------+----+--------+
```